# How to group google sourceMedium and count same referral

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I used Gapi.class.php to get data from google analytic.

Here is my php code

```
 $ga->requestReportData(xxxxx,array('sourceMedium','month','year'),array('sessions'), $sort_metric=array('month'), $filter=null, $start_date=$fromDate, $end_date=$toDate, $start_index=1, $max_results=10000);
```

I got like this

```js
[dimensions:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array
                (
                    [sourceMedium] => l.facebook.com / referral
                    [month] => 06
                    [year] => 2016
                )
   [dimensions:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array
                (
                    [sourceMedium] => mail.google.com / referral
                    [month] => 06
                    [year] => 2016
                )
     [dimensions:gapiReportEntry:private] => Array
                (
                    [sourceMedium] => mbasic.facebook.com / referral
                    [month] => 06
                    [year] => 2016
                )
```

I want to know how can I group them and count,

```
Example 
        source   Count
         fb    =  100
        google =  50
```

Please.

## Updated

[image]

Comment: Do you want counts of exact sources lilke `1.facebook.com`,  `mail.google.com` or you want to group sources into categories lile fb, google and than count the sessions?

Comment: @dikesh, Please, take a look my updated post again. 
I want certain page of source pageviews as I updated.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove date related dimensions i.e. `month` and `year` from your query to get aggregated numbers.

So your query should look something like this to get expected output.

```
$ga->requestReportData(xxxxx,array('sourceMedium','pagePath'), array('pageviews'), $sort_metric=array('pageviews'), $filter=null, $start_date=$fromDate, $end_date=$toDate, $start_index=1, $max_results=10000);
```

Have a look at following links for your references.

[Google Analytics Dimension and Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

[Creating Reports](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics)

[Advanced Use Cases of Creating Reports](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced)